# Understanding relative homotopy through a simple example

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $X$ be a space and $x_0 \in X$. Suppose thta $f,g:X \to S^1$ are maps such that $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ and that $f \simeq g$. Show that $f \simeq g \text{ rel }x_0$. Hint: If $h:f \simeq g$, then find a suitable rotation $u_t$ and define a new homotopy as $h'_t=u_t \circ h_t$.

I don't think I've fully understood the idea with homotopies relative to some point. Isn't $f \simeq g$ supposed to be a stronger argument than homotopy relative to single point?

Pictorially I see this as such that the image $f(X)$ is some segment wrapped around $S^1$ and similarly for $g(X)$ and as they're homotopic we can continuously deform them to be the same segment.

If this is the case then surely $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ is either in $f(X)$ or in $g(X)$ so why would I even need to look at this realtive to $x_0$ in the first place as it's already covered by the homotopy $f \simeq g$?

Comment: Homotopy relative to a single point requires the homotopy to **leave the image of that point fixed**, thus stronger than usual homotopy which only requires **the images of that point are the same at the start and the end**.

Comment: In your situation, if $h$ is just a homotopy, then the only requirement at $x_0$ is $h(x_0,0)=f(x_0)=g(x_0)=h(x_0,1)$; But if $h$ is a relative homotopy, then the requirement becomes $h(x_0,t)=f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.